# HostNameComparisonMode in WCF

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I have a WCF service self-hosted in my console application and trying to understand the hostNameComparisonMode binding attribute for basicHttpBinding. Here is my hosted WCF:

```
// Test for StrongWildCard
        ServiceHost serviceHostForStrong = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri("http://test1:8887/Service"));
        BasicHttpBinding basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        basicHttpBinding.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard;
        EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://abc1:8887/Service/ForStrong");
        ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint = 
            new ServiceEndpoint(ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(IServiceContract)),
                basicHttpBinding,
                endpointAddress);
        serviceHostForStrong.AddServiceEndpoint(serviceEndpoint);
        serviceHostForStrong.Open();

        // Test for Exact
        ServiceHost serviceHostForExact = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri("http://test2:8888/Service"));
        basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        basicHttpBinding.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.Exact;
        endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://abc2:8888/Service/ForExact");
        serviceEndpoint =
            new ServiceEndpoint(ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(IServiceContract)),
                basicHttpBinding,
                endpointAddress);
        serviceHostForExact.AddServiceEndpoint(serviceEndpoint);
        serviceHostForExact.Open();

        // Test for Weak
        ServiceHost serviceHostForWeak = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri("http://test3:8889/Service"));
        basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        basicHttpBinding.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.WeakWildcard;
        endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://abc3:8889/Service/ForWeak");
        serviceEndpoint =
            new ServiceEndpoint(ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(IServiceContract)),
                basicHttpBinding,
                endpointAddress);
        serviceHostForWeak.AddServiceEndpoint(serviceEndpoint);
        serviceHostForWeak.Open();

        Console.WriteLine("Service is running....Press any key to exit");
```

And here is my client side code:

```
EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8887/Service/ForStrong/ABC"); // Why it doesn't match with StrongWildCard
        BasicHttpBinding basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        ChannelFactory<IServiceContract> channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IServiceContract>(basicHttpBinding, endpointAddress);

        IServiceContract proxy = channelFactory.CreateChannel(endpointAddress);
        Console.WriteLine("Data received: " + proxy.GetData());
        Console.ReadKey();
```

As far as I understand from `http://kennyw.com/?p=109`, the URL `"http://localhost:8887/Service/ForStrong/ABC"` should match the StrongWildCard. However, it gives an exception at client when I try to run this code:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll Additional information: The message with To 'http://localhost:8887/Service/ForStrong/ABC' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher.  Check that the sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses agree.
```

Am I missing anything here or my understand is incorrect? Few more supporting questions:

1. Can you give me few examples (considering this as base) where it
   will use WeakWildCard URL?
2. How would I know which server side URL
   served my request?

Thanks!